Why the @PreAuthorize method with hasAnyAuthority('administrateur') always gives 403 forbidden?
i have configured my springboot application with keycloak 18.0.2.
here's my SecurityConfig class

import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.servlet.util.matcher.MvcRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector;

@Configuration
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableMethodSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {

        MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvcMatcherBuilder =
                new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize
                                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(HttpMethod.GET, "/swagger-ui.html")).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(HttpMethod.GET, "/swagger/**")).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(HttpMethod.GET, "/swagger-ui/**")).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(HttpMethod.GET, "/v3/api-docs/**")).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(HttpMethod.GET, "/health")).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(HttpMethod.GET, "/info")).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")).permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ).oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }
}


this is my configuration:
spring: 
      security:
        oauth2:
            resource-server:
                jwt:
                    issuer-uri: https://{KC_host}:{KC_PORT}/auth//auth/realms/{REALM}
                    jwk-set-uri: ${spring.security.oauth2.resource-server.jwt.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
            client:
                registration:
                    myClient:
                        client-id: myClient
                        client-secret: {secret}
                        provider: myClient
                        scope: openid, profile
                        authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
                provider:
                    myClient:
                        token-uri: https://{KC_host}:{KC_PORT}/auth/realms/{REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/token
                        authorization-uri: https://{KC_host}:{KC_PORT}/auth/realms/{REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/auth
                        user-info-uri: https://{KC_host}:{KC_PORT}/auth/realms/{REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
                        jwk-set-uri: https://{KC_host}:{KC_PORT}/auth/realms/{REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
                        user-name-attribute: preferred_username

when i invoke the API without the @PreAuthorize annotation it works fine but when i try to secure it in the controller with the @PreAuthorize annotation:
 @GetMapping("/all")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('administrateur')")
    public ResponseEntity<List<contexts>> findAllContexts() {
        return new ResponseEntity(contextService.findAllContexts(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

i always get a 403 forbidden response. The user is configured with this client role "administarteur" in keycloak.
i am using Java 17, springboot 3.1.2, keycloak-version 18.0.2.
when i turn the debug mode for springframework security, i get this:
2024-04-12T16:40:50.497+01:00 DEBUG 7520 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /context/all
2024-04-12T16:40:51.018+01:00 DEBUG 7520 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Authenticated token
2024-04-12T16:40:51.019+01:00 DEBUG 7520 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] .s.r.w.a.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@bca1db30, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[SCOPE_profile, SCOPE_email]]
2024-04-12T16:40:51.035+01:00 DEBUG 7520 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /context/all
2024-04-12T16:40:51.048+01:00 DEBUG 7520 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Authorizing method invocation ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.test.controler.findAllContexts(); target is of class [com.test.controler.ContextController]
2024-04-12T16:40:51.056+01:00 DEBUG 7520 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Failed to authorize ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.test.controler.ContextController.findAllContexts(); target is of class [com.test.controler.ContextController] with authorization manager org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.DeferringObservationAuthorizationManager@6e52d80 and decision ExpressionAuthorizationDecision [granted=false, expressionAttribute=hasAnyAuthority('administrateur')]


anyone can provide me a possible solution.
i tried using hasRole with the "ROLE_" prefix but it did not worked. i modified keycloak config to assign the role "administrateur" as a realm role instead of client role but in vain

Try @EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) with @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('administrateur')") or @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_administrateur')")

This has been answered many, may times: you are not mapping roles claim(s) to Spring authorities. Does this answer your question? Use Keycloak Spring Adapter with Spring Boot 3

i've tried them all, it doesn't work

well, try again, because the accepted answer from the link above works

I resolved the issue by using @EnableMethodSecurity annotation and ".anyRequest().fullyAauthenticated()" instead of  ".anyRequest().authenticated()"
